# Applications of the class number formula, etc

Tags: big-list, algebraic-number-theory

This is a big list of applications of the class number formula and its generalizations. I'll start:

1. The solution to [Gauss's class number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem) for imaginary quadratic fields, and more generally the [Brauer-Siegel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Siegel_theorem).
2. The comparison of the class number of a field with the class numbers of its subfields.
3. The application of the Beilinson-Bloch conjecture to the arithmetic Bogomolov-Miyoaka-Yau inequality. See [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/distinguished-lecture-series-iii-shou-wu-zhang-%E2%80%9Ctriple-l-series-and-effective-mordell-conjecture%E2%80%9D/).
4. The explicit construction of class fields of totally real fields via [Stark's conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_conjectures).

What else?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if each entry in the list came with some more substantial exposition than just a link.  You might do this by putting them in separate answers, and writing a short summary of what you're linking.  This way, your question becomes a place to actually read about the class number formula, instead of just a list of links.  Secondly, the lack of an explanation of the class number formula or a link to say a Wikipedia page suggests you only intend the list for people who already know the formula well, and I think the question would be more attractive if you changed that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I like them. I'll implement them when I have a chance (though it may take me some time to do so, as there's a lot of expository material to write up).

Comment: In the same spirit of Scott's comment I suggest to give a link to the class number formula itself and to introduce it in a few sentences in the body of the question. 

Comment: In light of the paucity of answers, perhaps the "big-list" tag should be replaced by "empty-list"?